# Overloaded == and comparison with nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am writing a C++/CLI wrapper of a C++ Native Static Library.

I don't have much experience with either C++/CLI or C++. I have followed best practices I read on internet for the creation of C++/CLI wrappers. My wrapper has a pointer to the C++ class. And my C++ has the operator == overloaded.

I am trying to overload it also in my wrapper and use the implementation of the C++ class, but I am getting errors when the wrapper is null.

I searched how to know if my handle is null, and I found that you have to compare it with nullptr.

**I have this method in C++/CLI**

```
       MyOtherClass const* MyClass::MyMethod(MyWrapper^ instance)   
    {
        if(instance == nullptr)
        {
           return NULL;
        }

        return instance->Property;      
    }
```

The line **if(instance == nullptr)** calls  my overloaded implementation of the **==** operator.

```
      static bool operator==(MyWrapper^ a, MyWrapper^ b)
    {
        return a->InternalInstance == b->InternalInstance; //Here System.AccessViolationException Exception
    }
```

The problem is that if **a** is null, this will throw an System.AccessViolationException exception.

And I cant just simply add a comparison with nullptr for **a** and **b**, because It creates a stack overflow.

```
static bool operator==(MyWrapper^ a, MyWrapper^ b)
{
    if(a == nullptr && b == nullptr) //Stack Overflow here because a == nullptr calls this method again.
        return true;
    if((a == nullptr && b != nullptr) || (a != nullptr && b == nullptr))
        return false;
    return a->InternalInstance == b->InternalInstance;
}
```

How can I override the **==** operator to use my C++ Native implementation, and still be protected of my handle being null?

Comment: You could have an explicit overloaded `bool()` operator that returns true if `MyWrapper ^` is not a null ptr

Comment: `if (a && b && a->InternalInstance == b->InternalInstance)` should do it.  If either `a` or `b` is `NULL`, it would evaluate to `false`, so the other conditionals would never get executed.

Comment: @ZacHowland I tried with return a && b && a->internalUnit == b->internalUnit;, but that doesn't work, it throws object reference. I think this happens because when I debug the handle is "undefined". I guess this is not similar to what C++ would do.

Comment: @Dzyann That may be something specific to the CLI, but if the pointer is `NULL` or `nullptr`, it should equate to `false` if you had a statement `if (a)`.  The other option is to use `ReferenceEquals`.

Comment: @ZacHowland you are right, that is what I expected, and that is why I tested out your code, I wanted to know what was going to actually do, for example would it call a == NULL internally when you do "a &&.."?. Well I don't know what it does, but in C++/CLI your suggestion sadly doesn't work. I even tried setting a = nullptr the line before the return to see if it was related with the fact that I didn't initialize a, but it fails anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Object::ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) to explicitly check for null.

```
static bool operator==(MyWrapper^ a, MyWrapper^ b)
{
    if(Object::ReferenceEquals(a, nullptr) && Object::ReferenceEquals(b, nullptr))
        return true;

    if(Object::ReferenceEquals(a, nullptr) || Object::ReferenceEquals(b, nullptr))
        return false;

    return a->InternalInstance == b->InternalInstance;
}
```

Comment: No need to prefix with `Object::`.  It's inherited.

Comment: I know, but I think it's generally good practice to specify the class name when calling static methods.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the overloaded function o == operate is performed on a reference type in C++/CLI, so if we follow the same way to do this in the native C++, it means that overloaded function of == operator is performed on a pointer type. But in native C++, we usually define == operator like this:

```
bool operator==(const X& lhs, const X& rhs){ /* do actual comparison */ }
```

Or think this way, if you overload the == for the pointer type in native C++, how can you compare this class pointer with null?

In the managed world, By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by determining if two references indicate the same object, so reference types do not need to implement operator == in order to gain this functionality. So you should implement the  Equals function instead of overloading ==

Please refer this: [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) . Though it is about C#, I think it is apply the managed types in C++/CLI too.

Comment: So, I override the operator following another question here in SO. But it doesn't make sense? It should read bool operator==(const X% lhs, const X% rhs) instead of bool operator==(const X^ lhs, const X^ rhs) like I have it. Because now that you mention it, I have never seen a bool operator==(const X* lhs, const X* rhs). Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: And doing operator==(const X% lhs, const X% rhs) is pointless (not a good idea) for no inmutable objects like the link mentions because the framework implementation already compares for reference equality. In my case however, I have an inmutable object and I can use what David posted, that it is also suggested in your link. Thanks great info.